# Long run probability of going to a state from another

Tags: probability, markov-chains

We consider the following transition matrix for a markov chain with state space {A,B,C,D,E} :

$P= \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 &0 &\frac{1}{2} \\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\frac{1}{2} &0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0\\
0 &\frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{4}\\
\frac{1}{2} &0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{2}\end{array} \right) $

(a) find its stationary distrbutions.

(b) Suppose we start in state B. In the long run, what is the probability that we are in state A at any given time?

Attempt: We observe here that A,C,E are recurrent states and B,D are transient. I have found out the stationary distributions to be $(0,0,1,0,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{2}, 0,0,0,\frac{1}{2})$

How do we do the second part?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: A heuristic approach to the second part: the long run question asks which stationary distribution you 'fall into'.  If you wind up in the A/E distribution then your odds of being in state A at a given time are $\frac12$; if you wind up in the C distribution then your odds of being in state A are 0.  Now, consider the transitions out of B; can you see what controls whether you'll wind up in A/E or C, and what the relative probabilities are?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? It says that we have to be state A at any given time. How do we find that long run probability?

Answer (score 1):

You have two ergodic SCC: $\{A,E\}$ and $\{C\}$. The probability you are looking for is the probability to reach $\{A,E\}$. This can be computed via absorbing Markov Chains:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain

To sum up the wikipedia page, you have to consider the 2*2 matrix $Q$ of transitions between transient states ($B$ and $D$) and the 2*2 matrix $R$ that gives  the transition from B and D to components $\{A,E\}$ and $\{C\}$.
You get
$Q=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{2}& \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{4} \end{array}\right)$

and
$R= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0& 0 \\
\frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{4}\end{array} \right)$.

Then you compute the matrix $X=(I-Q)^{-1}R$, and the entry (1,1) is the probability you are looking for: reaching $\{A,E\}$ from $B$ (section "Absorbing probabilities" on wikipedia).

Notice that here, no computation is necessary, as the matrix $R$ is unchanged by swapping columns, you will get probability $\frac{1}{2}$ for each component.

Comment: To nitpick, once you're in the {A,E} set, you still have to multiply by $\frac12$ (the probability of being in A given that you're in {A,E}).

Comment: right, so essentially it's 1/4 , thank you Steven and Dkuper, thanks a lot.

Comment: yes once you are in the component you still have 1/2 to be in A and 1/2 to be in E. I understood the question "the proba to reach A at some point in the run"